# Is it safe to create view in memory with unsafe.Pointer to []byte cast

Tags: go, cgo

I have a data structure that should be filled by some external C code in kernel

```
type Data struct { 
    buf1 [100]byte
    buf2 [100]byte 
}
```

I wrote a function that takes `[]byte` and passes it to that external code to be filled

```
func (p *port) send(request []byte, responce []byte) error {
    res, _, _ := portProc.Call(uintptr(*p),
        uintptr((*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&request)).Data),
        uintptr(len(request)),
        uintptr((*reflect.SliceHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&responce)).Data),
        uintptr(len(responce)))

    if res != 0 {
        return syscall.Errno(res)
    }

    return nil
}
```

From the next explanation https://pkg.go.dev/unsafe#Pointer it is not clear to me if the next code is safe. So is it?

```
var response = new(Data)
var responseByteSlice = (*(*[unsafe.Sizeof(*response)]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(response)))[:]

var request = 4
var requestByteSlice = (*(*[unsafe.Sizeof(request)]byte)(unsafe.Pointer(&request)))[:]

port.send(request, response)
```

Comment: The last block of code doesn't seem safe to me since you never check the size of `response` or `request` if they are larger than 100 you will be accessing memory outside of the `Data` instance which might cause strange behavior at best or cause the OS to terminate the program for accessing memory not assigned to it(Segfault).

Comment: I suggest taking a look at how the standard library interfaces with syscalls to see how to do it safely, for example: https://cs.opensource.google/go/go/+/refs/tags/go1.18.1:src/syscall/zsyscall_linux_amd64.go;drc=refs%2Ftags%2Fgo1.18.1;l=88

Comment: the question is not within 100 bytes limit but in the safety of using the view of the data structure by casting to byte array. If for example after `responseByteSlice` initialization runtime decides to increase stack size and copy all data on the stack to a new location will `responseByteSlice` point to the same location in memory as before the stack move or pointer will be updated?

Comment: AFAIK Go will always allocate on the heap if a reference to the variable leaves the function scope, so you will never have the memory location of a stack object. Heap objects never change location, the runtime tracks references to the variable, if non exist it may be collected by the GC. By using an `unsafe.Pointer` you lose this reference. So this is "safe" as long as you always have a "normal" reference to the `response` and `request` when using 'responseByteSlice' so the runtime will not GC the memory

Comment: thanks, just small clarification, it is not guaranteed that heap objects never change location. But anyway I just was curious if `responseByteSlice` can share GC reference with `response`. I'm new in go.